Yet another alignment issue with \systeme
Fellow TeX-ers,
Can you lend me a helping hand?
How should I modify the code below in order for all the \sin \alpha, \cos \beta, and \tan \gamma to be displayed in the same column?
$$
\systeme{
2 \sin \alpha - \cos \beta + 3\tan \gamma= 3,
4 \sin \alpha + 2\cos \beta - 2\tan \gamma = 2,
6 \sin \alpha - 3\cos \beta + \tan \gamma = 9
}
$$

I am attaching a screen-shot of what I get when I compile this... Thanks in advance for your cooperation!


systeme only deals with “simple” variables, but provides \syssubstitute.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}
\[
\syssubstitute{{x}{\sin\alpha}{y}{\cos\beta}{z}{\tan\gamma}}
\systeme{
  2x -  y + 3z = 3,
  4x + 2y - 2z = 2,
  6x - 3y +  z = 9
}
\]

\end{document}


Don't use $$ in LaTeX, see Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?

Your TeX-ness is off the charts.
